# How to count the number of documents firestore on flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to calculate how many documents are in a collection, not the length of the document. I have tried it with some code but what appears is the length of the character from my document name.

[image]

this my code :

```
StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> userpost;
    final DocumentReference documentReference =
        Firestore.instance.document("product/$documentPost");
    userpost = documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        for (int i = 0; i < datasnapshot.data.length; i++){
           print(datasnapshot.data.length);
        }
```

Comment: why you blackmarked the image???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An Example Function to fetch Documents Count.

```
void countDocuments() async {
    QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection('product').getDocuments();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.documents;
    print(_myDocCount.length);  // Count of Documents in Collection
}
```

Comment: how to show inside buildContext of scaffold, that is how to show on screen? any help

Comment: This requires download of all data? Are there no better way?

Comment: too much resources, only for get count, any other solutions?

Comment: Every document read leads to 1 read count in firebase pricing. This solution is very bad because just to get the number of documents in a collection you have to read every document.

Comment: oh~~no! this is bad solution.

Comment: you can use the `count`function to only get the number of documents

Comment: While this may work, this reads all documents in your collection. Please see @jbryanh solution below. This uses a `count` query to obtain this information.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `count()` function which was added in cloud_firestore version 4.0.0

Accepted answer might be a bad solution because you have to fetch all the documents just to count the number of documents. As per [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing), every document read is taken as 1 read count.

So a better solution is to use the `count()` function instead.

```dart
AggregateQuerySnapshot query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('random_collection').count().get();

int numberOfDocuments = query.count;
```

`count()` is an [Aggregation Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries)

PS: You might need to update your firebase plugins in pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 7):

With Cloud Firebase 2.0, there is a new way to count documents in a collection. According to reference notes, the count does not count as a read per document but a metaData request:

"[AggregateQuery] represents the data at a particular location for retrieving metadata without retrieving the actual documents."

Example:

```
final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> userList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<int> countUsers() async {
    AggregateQuerySnapshot query = await userList.count().get();
    debugPrint('The number of users: ${query.count}');
    return query.count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 solution

```
collectionSum()async{
var myRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName');
var snapshot = await myRef.count().get();
print('collection Sum ${snapshot.count}');
```

}