# how can i count the number of document from firestore and return it in a text

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

I want to calculate how many documents are in a collection,

```
child: Card(
                      child: ListTile(

                          title: FlatButton.icon(
                              onPressed: null,

                              icon: Icon(Icons.people_outline),
                              label: Text("Users")),
                          subtitle: Text( Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().length.toString() , textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 12.0),)),
                    ),
```

Comment: what did you try till now and what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of documents firestore on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456665/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-firestore-on-flutter)

Comment: Note that loading all data from a collection only to determine the document count is a very wasteful operation. I highly recommend storing the count itself in the database too, and updating it each time you add/remove a user. Also see the documentation on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters