# Flutter: how to count items in a Firebase field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the amount of items I have in this document field (ingredients) as integer? (in this case 5)
[image]

I tried this:

```
void countDocuments() async {
  QuerySnapshot _myDoc =
  await Firestore.instance.collection('product').getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.documents;
  print(_myDocCount.length); // Count of Documents in Collection
}
```

But that seems not to work in my case:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to map the Map to a list and count how many keys/values that Map has. Have you tried something so far? You need to show progress.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456665/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-firestore-on-flutter but the 'firestore' keyword seems to cause trouble in my case

Comment: firestore keyword? What do you mean? Could you show your code? Did you downloaded the library and imported?

Comment: Please, re check your code. You defined a variable on top of your method and then you're trying to call a class that doesn't exist because "Firebase" is not defined... Its called "FirebaseFirestore"

Comment: Sorry I just copy pasted it from the other post here. Thank you for replying

Comment: Please, always take a double look at anything you copy, as the answer could be super old and deprecated. You can guide yourself by official documentations as the Firebase team does a great job with that.

Comment: The question is unclear; are you having trouble connecting to Firebase in the first place or having trouble determining the field count? e.g. the question seems to indicate you're not able to retrieve *any* data so can you clarify that part?Getting a field count; Firebase returns data in a Snapshot, and that has a `data` component which are the individual fields. Data has a map - like this `snapshot.data() map`  MOST IMPORTANTLY, don't store data that way; either store your ingredients in an array with two fields, ingredient and qty or store in a map with documentId's and data under that.

Answer (score 2):

please follow the official documentation to connect with Firebase Firestore.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance` instead of `Firestore.instance`