# How to do this for Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show in my code as Text the length of the document from a specific collection like this one.

I want to show in Flutter how many document inside "Agung"
[this is the ss of my Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGqy0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456665/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-firestore-on-flutter)

to show how many documents you have inside **Agung** you can use :

```
int countDocuments() async {
        QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection('Agung').getDocuments();
        List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.documents;
        return _myDocCount.length;  // Count of Documents in Collection
    }
```

Then you can just call the function and put the result on your Text Widget

Comment: @ShinnKun Thats great ! it would be appreciated then if you accept my answer